# Replace pattern in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have the following text:

```
String text = "lorem ipsum @@MyText[1] lorem ipsum @@MyText[22]";
```

And I want to replace it by:

```
String text = "lorem ipsum /my/url/1 lorem ipsum /my/url/22;
```

I have done the following:

```
String newText = text.replaceAll("@@MyText\\[\\d*\\]", "/my/url/%s");
```

But in this way I get:

```
"lorem ipsum /my/url/%s lorem ipsum /my/url/%s;
```

How could I replace the given text but still conservating the number in the brackets?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: You could capture the number using parentheses and use that in the replacement, I think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to place number found in `[...]` in separate group and use match from that group in replacement via `$id` where `id` represents number of that group.

Use

```
replaceAll("@@MyText\\[(\\d+)\\]",       "my/url/$1")
//                     ^^^^^^ group 1            ^^ part matched by group 1
```

Comment: That's it! I did it in a more complex way: "(@@MyText\\[)(\\d*)(\\])", and then using $2, but I prefer your solution. Thank you!